# How do I set default picture if no picture is uploaded using paperclip gem on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my code:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  has_attached_file :avatar,
                       :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                       :default_url => ":style/missing.jpg" 
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

Also, my image is stored in app/assets/images/medium as missing.jpg and in app/assets/images/thumbs as missing.jpg. Right now the error that I get is that it simply displays the word missing and no picture.

Below is the code to display the picture in my view file.

```
<div class="profile-image">
    <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url %>       
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what issues you're running into? We can't help you unless you clearly explain what you're trying to do, what you've done, and what issue you've ran into.

Comment: Sorry, i just did. Basically, it displays the name of the file which is "missing" and not the actual image

Comment: Can you post a short snippet of you attempting to use the avatar URL? so we can see where the error originates from? Try to keep it concise (don't post the entire view)

Comment: Okay, I put the snippet of my view file in the post.

Comment: Do you have any image named "missing.jpg" in your style directory, as you mentioned your default URL is "style/missing.jpg". If not then place a image in this directory with same name, and then all works fine

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work as well.